# Problem with ASUS V2S lcd screen - Inverter or Lcd screen?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

I'm pretty worried about my Asus V2S Laptop. I don't know what is wrong? Reading in web, I think it could be the inverter board or the lcd screen itself (Review the flex cable, and it's ok). Here I leave you some pictures, so you can help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other symptoms are laptop inestability.

I re-install Windows Vista Ultimate, sometimes using external monitor, but still I got instability.

Could be other the problem? like the video chip?

Comment: Sounds and looks like a bad video chip to me.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen the video signal pattern on your 2nd photo is when the video card is bad/malfunctioning. It's probably getting close to being 4 years old which is the "average life span"[1] for a laptop.

If you really need the laptop to work, you could send it back to Asus to be repaired. I'm guessing that this machine is out of warranty so they will charge you for parts and labor.

If I was in your situation, I would find the cash to just buy a replacement machine. You can get really good laptops in the $500 to $800 range these days.

Good Luck

[1] This is "conventional wisdom" not backed up by facts or studies.